# Combine 2 kde-functions in one plot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code for plotting the histogram and the kde-functions (Kernel density estimation) of a training and validation dataset:

```
#Plot histograms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns



displot_dataTrain=sns.displot(data_train, bins='auto', kde=True)
displot_dataTrain._legend.remove()
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Training Data')
plt.title("Histogram Training Data")
plt.show()

displot_dataValid =sns.displot(data_valid, bins='auto', kde=True)
displot_dataValid._legend.remove()
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Validation Data')
plt.title("Histogram Validation Data")
plt.show()

# Try to plot the kde-functions together --> yields an AttributeError
X1 = np.linspace(data_train.min(), data_train.max(), 1000)
X2 = np.linspace(data_valid.min(), data_valid.max(), 1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,6))
ax[0].plot(X1, displot_dataTest.kde.pdf(X1), label='train')
ax[1].plot(X2, displot_dataValid.kde.pdf(X1), label='valid')
```

The plotting of the histograms and kde-functions inside one plot works without problems. Now I would like to have the 2 kde-functions inside one plot but when using the posted code, I get the following error `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'kde'`

Do you have any idea, how I can combined the 2 kde-functions inside one plot (without the histogram)?

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks Johan for your answer. When using your suggested code `ax[0].plot(X1, sns.kdeplot(data=data_train, ax=ax[0]), label='train')

ax[0].plot(X2, sns.kdeplot(data=data_valid, ax=ax[0]), label='valid')` I get the following error "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)"

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Actually I tried what you said and it works. However, there are 2 things that I don't understand. I have the following code `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,6))
sns.kdeplot(data=data_train, label='train', ax=ax[0], color='red')
sns.kdeplot(data=data_valid, label='valid', ax=ax[0], color='green')`.

Comment: 1) The color information does not have any effect (the plots are both blue). How can I use different colors for the different functions? 2) The current code creates 2 figures but I only want to have 1 figure. However, when using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,6))' I get the error message "TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sns.displot()` returns a `FacetGrid`. That doesn't work as input for `ax.plot()`. Also, `displot_dataTest.kde.pdf` is never valid. However, you can write `sns.kdeplot(data=data_train, ax=ax[0])` to create a `kdeplot` inside the first subplot. See the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html); note the optional parameters `cut=` and `clip=` that can be used to adjust the limits.

If you only want one subplot, you can use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12,6))` and use `ax=ax` instead of `ax=ax[0]` as in that case `ax` is just a single subplot, not an array of subplots.

The following code has been tested using the latest seaborn version:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.kdeplot(data=np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 100).cumsum(),
            color='crimson', label='train', fill=True, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(data=np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 100).cumsum(),
            color='limegreen', label='valid', fill=True, ax=ax)
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining two kdeplots]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. Unfortunately, the color attribute still does not have any effect. The curvers remain blue when using the following code :`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
sns.kdeplot(data=data_train, color='crimson', label='train', fill=True, ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(data=data_valid,  color='limegreen', label='valid', fill=True, ax=ax)
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()`

Comment: If `data_train` is of shape `(N,1)`, you need to `squeeze` it for seaborn to interpret it as a 1D array instead of a 2D one.  The 2D arrays always use the palette.  So, `sns.kdeplot(data=data_train.squeeze(), color='crimson')` . Or, when using the "2D" data: `sns.kdeplot(data=data_train, palette=['crimson'])`.  (Maybe this helps understand why people always ask for test data on StackOverflow? Seaborn accepts a multitude of data formats as input.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The data_train is a numpy array (array of float64) with the shape (5672, 1). The `data_valid' is also a numpy array (float64) with the shape (1620,1). Here is some test data https://filetransfer.io/data-package/BXrIxBfh#link

Comment: `sns.kdeplot(data={'train': data_train.squeeze(), 'valid': data_valid.squeeze()}, palette=['crimson', 'limegreen'], common_norm=False)` could be another way, drawing everything in one go, including the legend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. Yes, now it works using squeeze(). However, I noticed that the fonts on the x and y axis and on the legend are quite small. Do you know, how I can change that?

Comment: `sns.set(font_scale=1.7)` to be called at the start

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using your suggested code something really strange happens. All seaborn plots change their background to a blue/grey background and the diagrams look quite different now (which I don't like). The strange thing is, that even after deleting your suggested line `sns.set(font_scale=1.7)` and rerunning the code, the figures still have this strange background and formatting. So I don't like this option at all. I figured out that you can increase the font with`plt.xticks(fontsize =20)
plt.yticks(fontsize =20)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using `sns.set_theme("ticks")` I get the error message `ValueError: context must be in paper, notebook, talk, poster` thrown by this very line

Comment: Probably it needs to be `sns.set_style('ticks')`.  See also [Seaborn aesthetics](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html).  Note that StackOverflow's purpose is to help with programming questions that aren't easily solvable in another way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.